# How to increase vm.max_map_count and max file descriptors for ElasticSearch in Jelastic?

Tags: jelastic

I'm trying to run dockerized ElasticSearch 5.0.1 on Jelastic.
During startup it prints to the logs:

```
max file descriptors [4096] for elasticsearch process is too low,  
increase to at least [65536] max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count 
[65530] is too low, increase to at least [262144]
```

How do I change these parameters? Increasing reserved cloudlets count didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must contact your hosting provider for this. You cannot change this parameter from within; it has to be performed by the hosting provider at the virtualisation platform side.

Comment: Thanks, contacted my provider and they fixed all the things.